# updating in batch one to many relationship rails 2.3.5 one sql statement?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Lets say user has many accounts, so user_id is on accounts table. If I want to update all the users accounts and give them to another user in 1 sql call is there a "rails" way to do this? (without doing executeSQL)

So Joel has 1000 accounts, Fred has no accounts, Joel wants to give Fred all his accounts, normally I could iterate through joels accounts and assign them to fred user, but that would result in 1000 sql calls..

Answer (score 0):

```
fred.accounts += joel.accounts
```

This will **immediately** move all accounts from `joel` and add them to any existing accounts that `fred` has. By "immediate" I mean the SQL will execute the update right away - you don't need to additionally save the records that are being moved.

If `fred` has no accounts, that's fine too, it still works the same - it will simply add `joel`'s accounts to `fred`'s empty list of accounts.

This works with both "one-to-many" and "many-to-many" relationship.

In the one-to-many situation, it does this my changing the `user_id` field on the `accounts` table for all accounts previously owned by `joel`.

In the many-to-many situation (where accounts can be co-owned by multiple users), it appears to simply change the `user_id` field on the join table (presumably called `accounts_users`) for all accounts that `joel` co-owns with zero or more other users. This effectively **replaces** any accounts that `joel` co-owned with `fred`. All other co-owners on the account are unaffected, it seems.

Comment: Updated my answer. The line does the same thing (a move from one user to another) with **both** one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.

Comment: What is triggering the extra statements? Have you checked to see if, perhaps, those are coming from ActiveRecord callbacks (such as `after_save`, `after_update`, etc.)?

Comment: A friend of mine and I used this gem this weekend to track down some ActiveRecord-triggered queries. Might be useful: https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace

Comment: no callbacks, I only did the call above and it triggered 1 update sql call for each record (3 statements)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I guess I misunderstood. You're saying that it's doing one SQL query per account that's being moved, and you want to avoid that? I guess that's to be expected - maybe you have to drop to raw SQL to do it using a sub-select? Ex: http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1651050-update-multiple-rows-single-sql-statement.html